# Pandas dataframe, organization and calculation

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I need help - I've spent all day (14+ hours) trying to set up a panda dataframe for a test file that I made. My real file is a csv that is several million lines long so I am trying to find the fastest and most effective way of handling the data. What I need to do is calculate year over year changes in prices for a list of items.

The data I have looks like this after I drop the unneeded columns:

```
Item    Price   As of Date
Item 1  1.08908 4/13/2016
Item 2  2.03281 4/13/2016
Item 3  3.02619 4/13/2016
Item 1  1.56743 12/21/2015
Item 3  12.31867    12/21/2015
Item 2  0.98066 12/21/2015
Item 4  0.31701 12/21/2015
Item 3  0.6251  3/31/2015
Item 1  6.87538 3/31/2015
Item 2  0.3113  3/31/2015
Item 4  0.18724 3/31/2015
```

First, I need to get the data into a way that I can make the year over year calculation. It is arranged with columns for the Item, Price, and the As of Date. I need to somehow arrange the data and calculate for each date that is given, what the year over year percentage change in price is per item listed. And then find the average of the changes per date.

Below is what I have tried to do to arrange the data, but I am having trouble figuring out which way is best and then how to calculate the y/y change.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('...python test file.csv')
asofdate = set ()

#sorting the dataframe chronologically by As of Date
df.sort_values(df.columns[11])

asofdate = list(df.apply(set)[11])
asofdate = [dt.datetime.strptime(date, '%m/%d/%Y').date() for date in asofdate]

#attempt 1
df = df.set_index("As of Date")
df = df[['Item','Price_Per_Unit']]

#attempt 2
df2 = df.pivot_table('Price_Per_Unit',['Item'], 'As of Date')

#date of lastupdate
lastupdated = df2.iloc[:,-1]
```

What I have to deal with the dates not being exact years is the below function (found on stackexchange) to find the most recent date:

```
def nearest(items, pivot):
    return min(items, key=lambda x: abs(x - pivot))
```

I know this is a pretty in depth question, but I would really appreciate any help or guidance anyone can provide. I've been reading tons of other posts but please feel free to share some if you think they'd be helpful. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure whether my understanding about your problem is right, have a look at snippet below.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] < 3: 
    from StringIO import StringIO
else:
    from io import StringIO



def get_prev_year_price(x, df):
    try:
        return df.loc[x['prev_year_date'], 'price']
    except Exception as e: #not recommended to write in this way...just for demo
        return x['price']


TESTDATA=StringIO("""Item   price   date
Item 1  1.08908 4/13/2016
Item 2  2.03281 4/13/2016
Item 3  3.02619 4/13/2016
Item 1  1.56743 12/21/2015
Item 3  12.31867    12/21/2015
Item 2  0.98066 12/21/2015
Item 4  0.31701 12/21/2015
Item 3  0.6251  3/31/2015
Item 1  6.87538 3/31/2015
Item 2  0.3113  3/31/2015
Item 4  0.18724 3/31/2015""")

df = pd.read_csv(TESTDATA, sep="\t")


df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'],format='%m/%d/%Y')


data = []
for item in df['Item'].unique():
    item_df = df[df['Item'] == item] #select based on items
    select_dates = item_df['date'].unique()
    item_df.set_index('date', inplace=True) #set date as key index
    item_df = item_df.resample('D').mean().reset_index() #fill in missing date
    item_df['price'] = item_df['price'].interpolate('nearest') #fill in price with nearest price available
    item_df['prev_year_date'] = item_df['date'] - pd.DateOffset(years=1) #calculate 1 year ago date
    date_df = item_df[item_df.date.isin(select_dates)] #select datas with useful data
    item_df.set_index('date', inplace=True)
    date_df['prev_year_price'] = date_df.apply(lambda x: get_prev_year_price(x, item_df),axis=1)
    date_df['change'] = date_df['price'] / date_df['prev_year_price']-1
    date_df['Item'] = item
    data.append(date_df)
summary = pd.concat(data).sort_values('date')
print (summary)
```

Result as:

```
          date     price prev_year_date  prev_year_price    change    Item
0   2015-03-31   6.87538     2014-03-31          6.87538  0.000000  Item 1
0   2015-03-31   0.31130     2014-03-31          0.31130  0.000000  Item 2
0   2015-03-31   0.62510     2014-03-31          0.62510  0.000000  Item 3
0   2015-03-31   0.18724     2014-03-31          0.18724  0.000000  Item 4
265 2015-12-21   1.56743     2014-12-21          1.56743  0.000000  Item 1
265 2015-12-21   0.98066     2014-12-21          0.98066  0.000000  Item 2
265 2015-12-21  12.31867     2014-12-21         12.31867  0.000000  Item 3
265 2015-12-21   0.31701     2014-12-21          0.31701  0.000000  Item 4
379 2016-04-13   1.08908     2015-04-13          6.87538 -0.841597  Item 1
379 2016-04-13   2.03281     2015-04-13          0.31130  5.530067  Item 2
379 2016-04-13   3.02619     2015-04-13          0.62510  3.841129  Item 3
```

By the way, you could improve your efficiency or code by reading pandas built-in library. i.e how to get unique dates, how to convert dates

Comment: This is hugely helpful, thanks a ton for your help. The only issue I am having I think is with the interpolation, `item_df['price'] = item_df['price'].interpolate('nearest')`This is shifting the previous year price too far forward, for example if the current date is 6/30/17 and there was a price change on 7/2/16, the value from 7/2/16 is being used for the calculation rather than the price that was in effect at 6/30/16 - any idea how to correct for this?

Comment: because in your sample, you are using "nearest" function to do interpolation. In fact, there are other methods, i.e. bfill or ffill (it is just a way to fill in nan values). I will suggest you to search "pandas bfill" or "pandas ffill". It will sure help you solve the problem.